# Update assets files content at runtime with Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am fresh with Flutter, and I was able to load the content of XML file as String from Assets folder using this method

```
Future<String> loadAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/file.xml');
}
```

and yaml file

```
flutter:
   assets:
      - assets/
```

And it just works very well.

**My question is:** Can I update an attribute value or add some nodes to my XML file and save it on the same place at Assets folder at **Runtime** of Flutter app?

> In sentence: I want to install the application on the user's device with original file of XML and user can modify it at any time as long as the application installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. But you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) to save the modified file in app directory.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

> *An asset is a file that is bundled and deployed with your app, and is accessible at runtime.*
>
> ...
>
> *During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called the asset bundle, which apps can read from at runtime.*