# How would I store small structured database (few thousand rows and 20 columns) read only locally in flutter?

Tags: sql, excel, database, flutter, dart

I'm developing an app that shows technical data (technical data for pipes and equipment), the database would be few thousand rows with each row averaging 20 columns.
All data would be read-only , just a technical book for engineers.

This an example of my data, I have few of those sheets: http://www.drillingformulas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Casing-Data-sheet.pdf

Can anyone help with an example of how to store and retrieve/filter the data?

Any thoughts or experiences would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: questions seeking recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks Scott for your comment, Would put that into consideration in my upcoming questions, however for the moment I would like to know whether SQL would be the best option or not. if you have any thoughts I’d be thankful if you shared.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is not changing in the future I would convert the spreadsheet to JSON and save it to the `assets` folder. [Here's more on how to load JSON assets into Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757953/how-to-load-json-assets-into-flutter-app)

If your data will change in the future I would consider [fetching it from a server](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and no the data is not changing in the future.

Comment: What do you think from a performance point of you about storing them in maps in a separate dart file other than storing in json and decoding each time

Comment: I'm not sure which is more performant but storing a lot of data in a dart file seems wrong. I don't think the performance will be a problem but you can investigate your individual case with [Dart DevTools](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools). Other than that I think a JSON asset has multiple benefits. [Assets seem to be read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270322/update-assets-files-content-at-runtime-with-flutter) which prevents unwanted runtime changes. Also maintaining dart objects created at runtime from JSON of semi-structured data like yours seems easier to me.

Comment: You can read more about Flutters "Load sequence, performance, and memory" [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/performance#finding-the-flutter-resources).

Comment: Can I use filters with json? .. like if I wanna call all rows having column x = certain value? .. and then do further filter like getting all rows out of the result having column y = certain value?